# How do I assert that a string is in a list of strings?

Tags: vb.net, nunit

I'm trying to verify a value is within a list of acceptable values.

I'm trying this:

```
Assert.That("Dog", [Is].SubsetOf({"Cat", "Dog", "Fish"}))
```

I am getting error:

```
Expected: subset of < "Cat", "Dog", "Fish" >
  But was:  "Dog"
```

I am trying to avoid using .Contains.

```
Assert.That({"Cat", "Dog", "Fish"}.Contains("Dog"))
```

Something's wrong with my list, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fluent way:

```
Assert.That(someList, Contains.Item(someItem));
```

Comment: Thanks, Fluent was the word I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Assert.Contains works OK. I'm just trying to find a more "readable" method for myself.

```
 Assert.Contains("Dog", {"Cat", "Dog", "Fish"})
```

My favorite solution for this problem is to use an extension method, but I can't go creating new modules just to add [In]

```
<Extension()>
Function [In](Of TItem, TColl)(this As TItem, ParamArray items() As TColl)
    Return Array.IndexOf(items, this) > -1
End Function
```

Would like like this:

```
Assert.That(MyString, [In]({"Cat", "Dog", "Fish"}))
```